# Non-isomorphicity of $(\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z})(x)$ and $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})(x_1)(x_2)...(x_n)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, rational-functions

How does one go about proving that $(\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z})(x) \not\cong (\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})(x_1)(x_2)...(x_n)$ as rings?

Intuitively, I understand, but I am not sure how to make it concrete. I expect that I should assume that an isomorphism exists, but I am not sure from where I would derive a contradiction.

Comment: Well, $(\mathbb Z/p^n\mathbb Z)(x)$ is not a field unless $n=1$, so...

Comment: As rings, then.

Comment: Well, if $n>1$ the left hand side is not a field and the right hand side is a field, so certainly they are not isomorphic as rings! If $n=1$ then two are the same thing, so they are in particular isomorphic.

Comment: Hmmm... So you think that the question is a "trick" in the sense that it did not require any real machinery, just the realization that the set-up was "bad"? I can live with that, although I am ashamed to have not noticed it. :(

Comment: I have no idea where you got this so it is somewhat difficult to guess what the intention of having it there was!

Comment: Why is the lhs not a field?

Comment: If $n>1$, then $p\neq0$ in $\mathbb Z/p^n\mathbb Z$ yet $p^n=0$. That cannot happen in a field.